# Dealing with a dishonest employee as a consultant

Tags: management

I’m a consultant and have a good contract with a company.  I used to be an employee but am now working as consultant for them.  I have noticed one of the employees is feeding management some bs.  In some respects I want to tell management about it but in other respects I don’t want to rock the boat as I have a good gig.  This employee is rather powerful and we work well together but I feel management is being taken advantage by him because of the little technical knowledge management has.

Best scenario for the company would be to have independent technical auditor evaluate statements of this employee.

Comment: How does this employee's "bs" directly affect you?

Comment: I would say not much.  It hurts the company but not me.  Except if I point out some of it I might get better favor with management and can increase my fees.

Comment: Can you prove this person is being dishonest?  This situation can be very precarious for all involved once you bring your suspicions to light.

Comment: I can if there is independent technical expert.  But very hard to with management alone because they don’t have technical expertise to evaluate his statements.

Comment: `Except if I point out some of it I might get better favor with management and can increase my fees.` - So your motivation has no altruistic value, you're doing this simply for personal financial gain? That seems a bit... shady.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a suggestion, without naming names, that management might consider retaining either a consultant or full time technical lead (CTO).  You don't have to name names or indicate you suspect a problem, but indicate they might be well served by having someone like this help them understand what some of their teams are doing and if they are making good technology decisions.

Comment: my follow-up as CEO would be: What prompted you suggestion, OP? Which exactly decision you think we need help with?

Answer (score 1):

### Let it go.

Unless you are tasked with auditting this employee, don't.

You say yourself you are on good terms with the company. You say you are on good terms with the employee. You say that the issue doesn't effect you directly. This sounds like a great balance. I personally wouldn't disturb it.

It's even possible that management is more aware than you suspect and that saying something will only hurt you.

I would only change course if things started to effect me, or I felt that the manager/company were being put into a precarious position.

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to shine some light on it for their attention without making accusations or drawing any attention to you.

Let's say the coworker's unacceptable behaviour is "B". Find another item, "A", which upon examination leads to B. Familiarise the right person or people with item A, and let them figure out B on their own.

If your interest in solving this is not about taking credit for it, and it should not be, then find away to draw their attention to it which avoids drawing you in or invites anyone to question your motive.